# Convert NSString to Chunks of NSString that has a date format

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

This might be simple. I have searched, not found yet.

How do I convert the NSString @"20100216190205" to an NSString of format @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

ie: @"2010-02-16 19:02:05"

**EDIT:**
I wanted to avoid using the NSDateFormatter to be more generic, for other situations.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an NSDateFormatter?  They're not very difficult to implement and are specifically designed for this purpose.  See: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Comment: Why do you say "without using NSDateFormatter"?  Only because your example doesn't work?  How are you creating the formatter?

Comment: There's the Edit. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely as an exercise in writing code:

```
NSString* digits = @"20100216190205"; // this is probably a parameter somewhere
NSMutableString* formatted = [digits mutableCopy];
[formatted insertString:@":" atIndex:12];
[formatted insertString:@":" atIndex:10];
[formatted insertString:@" " atIndex:8];
[formatted insertString:@"-" atIndex:6];
[formatted insertString:@"-" atIndex:4];
NSLog(@"original string: %@ -> formatted: %@", digits, formatted);
```

But I agree: go easy on yourself, and use a date formatter for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract each substring, convert them into integers (`-intValue`), then use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html) to convert these into a date. And it is much more troublesome than using NSDateFormatter.

In your case, the NSDateFormatter's format needs to be set to `yyyyMMddHHmmss` before calling `-dateFromString:`, i.e.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"20100216190205"];
....
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I was supposed to use:
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set your `formatter`'s format to yyyyMMddHHmmss to parse the string you have in your example.  You'll need to either create a new formatter or modify the original formatter's  format to incorporate the more visually appealing one that you want (`@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`).